# C syntax: Is the following 'extern volatile const' behavior consistent among C compilers?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, constants, extern, consistency

I have done the following C experiment:
I have three files (**a.c**, **a.h**, **b.c**):

- **a.c**:

  ```
  #define _A_C_
  #include "a.h"
  #undef _A_C_

  #include <stdio.h>

  int v = 19; // some value
  void
  fa()
  {
          printf("a.c: v = %d\n", v);
  }
  ```
- **a.h**:

  ```
  #ifndef _A_H_
  #define _A_H_

  #ifndef _A_C_
      // before edit the following line was 'extern const int v;'
      extern volatile const int v;
  #endif

  void
  fa();

  #endif
  ```
- **b.c**:

  ```
  #include "a.h"
  #include <stdio.h>

  void
  fb()
  {
      printf("b.c: v = %d\n", v);
          //v = 5; // -> uncomment this and you will get a compile error
  }

  int
  main()
  {
      fa();
      fb();
      getch();
      return 0;
  }
  ```

What I want to obtain with this is to be able to modify a variable selectively.

So basically, **v** will be seen as `int` for **a.c** and as `const int` for the rest of the code (e.g. **b.c**).

With **GCC 4.8.1** this **links and behaves as expected**.

***I want to know if I can rely on this behavior across C compilers.***

Thank you

**EDIT**

Thanks to Pascal Cuoq, I have realized that `extern const int v;` in a.h needs to be modified to `extern volatile const int v;` to avoid compiler optimizations issues

**OTHER FACTS**

- where `extern const x` is syntactically valid, `const x` WILL CAUSE x to be exported as a symbol in the resulting object-file
- thus, another equivalent question is actually: is there any case where the exported symbol `const int x` **would be different in the resulting object file** than `int x`? (for instance, does COFF permit this?)

Comment: @hivert please read carefully, it's not the same question; basically in the post marked as answer for that question, the answerer says "And yes, it should exactly match the declaration in the translation unit it's actually declared in. Unless of course you are participating in the Underhanded C Programming Contest :-)". I have just demonstrated that I have found a way to avoid that imposition and asked if I can rely on it

Comment: plus, the linked post refers to C++, not C

Comment: question seems legit to me

Comment: You can rely on (a) something you have tested and verified to work, or on (b) luck. Undefined behaviour that produces desired effect across an undetermined set of compilers is luck.

Comment: The int and const int combination seems to work for Visual Studio even though I didn't expect it to.  Need to try it on an embedded system compiler where the const parts go into ROM and the non const parts go into RAM.

Comment: @n.m. I am not a C expert, in the sense that I haven't read C books/articles/standard specifications thoroughly. Thus, I am hoping for a qualified answer that points me to something like that; of course I am aware this is currently 'luck, but an answer such as described above would change this 'luck' into 'certainty' :)

Answer (score 2):

> `v` will be seen as `int` for a.c and as `const int` for the rest of the code (e.g. b.c).

Consider the function:

```
extern int v = 5;

int main()
{
  f();
  return v;
}
```

GCC will happily optimize the function above to `{ f(); return 5; }`. If `f()` comes from a file where `v` is not `const` and actually modifies `v`, the function `main()` will appear not to behave as expected.

So in conclusion it is not allowed by the standard and it actually breaks programs in practice.

**EDIT:** if you hope that not providing an initializer for the `const` declaration would help, consider the following:

```
$ cat o.c
extern const x;

main(){
  int y = x;
  f();
  y -= x;
  return y;
}

$ gcc -O3 -S o.c
$ cat o.s
...
main:
...
    call    f
    xorl    %eax, %eax /* This sets the return value of main. To zero. Hardcoded. */
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Actually there is no reference to `x` at all in the assembly file. It can be linked with other files, one of which provides `f`, and never complain that `x` is missing, much less that it has the wrong type.

The linker is not a static analyzer. It is not there to detect bugs, and just because files can be linked together does not mean that they work together. Do not take the fact that the linker does not produce warnings as a sign that your program is correct.

Comment: that is why in a.h v will NOT be initialized.

Comment: thank you, I have tested this and you are correct; also, adding a volatile in "extern const int a" (as in "extern volatile const int a" resolves this issue as well; edited my question with this in mind

Answer (score 1):

Even if `x` is not initialized in its external declaration, the compiler is free to consider that two occurrences of `x` in two distinct statements are equal. If you consider the following example

```
extern const int x;

extern void f(void);

int main () {
  const int y = x;
  f();
  return y-x;
}
```

with `x` and `f` defined in another file as such:

```
int x = 5;

void f() { x = 4; }
```

and compiles with `gcc -O1`, you will obtain a program whose exit value is `0`, while `-O0` will give you `1` . In other words, Pascal Cuoq's conclusion is the right one.